# Duplicate phone numbers for each contacts android

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

In my application i want to show a list with my contacts and their phone number of each one. So i get the contacts from the ContentProvider and then all the numbers of the phone and then i match them by the contact id. code is the following

```
fun Context.retrieveAllContacts(): List<ContactData> {
    val result: MutableList<ContactData> = mutableListOf()
    contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        CONTACT_PROJECTION,
        null,
        null,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC"
    )?.use {
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val contactId = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[0]))
                val firstName = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[2])) ?: ""
                val lastName = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[3])) ?: ""
                val initials = getInitials(firstName, lastName)
                result.add(ContactData(contactId, firstName, initials, mutableListOf(), null))
            } while (it.moveToNext())
        }
    }
    return result
}


fun Context.retrieveAllContactNumbers(): HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> {
    val contactsNumberMap = HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()
    val phoneCursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    )
    if (phoneCursor != null && phoneCursor.count > 0) {
        val contactIdIndex =
            phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)
        val numberIndex = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
            val contactId = phoneCursor.getString(contactIdIndex)
            val number: String = phoneCursor.getString(numberIndex)
            // check if the map contains key or not, if not then create a new array list with number
            if (contactsNumberMap.containsKey(contactId)) {
                contactsNumberMap[contactId]?.add(number)
            } else {
                contactsNumberMap[contactId] = arrayListOf(number)
            }
        }
        // contact contains all the number of a particular contact
        phoneCursor.close()
    }
    return contactsNumberMap
}
```

And after that i run a loop to make the correspondence

```
                val contactsListAsync = async { context?.retrieveAllContacts() ?: emptyList() }
                val contacts = contactsListAsync.await()
                val contactNumbersAsync = async { requireActivity().retrieveAllContactNumbers() }
                val contactNumbers = contactNumbersAsync.await()

                contacts.forEach { contactData ->
                    contactNumbers[contactData.contactId]?.let { numbers ->
                        numbers.forEach {
                            if (isValidIrisCellphoneNumber(PhoneNumberUtils.normalizeNumber(it)))
                                contactData.phoneNumbers.add(it)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

As i can see many contacts have the same number 2 or 3 or evan 4 times. I guess the "problem" comes from the `retrieveAllContactNumbers()` which fetchs numbers from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone`. Mostly, i want to know why is this happening and then how can i prevent it?

I also noticed this: I added a fake contact and i saw that in my list with 2 numbers. Perhaps it has to do with from where the contentResolver gets the numbers? For example Google account, SIM card, Internal storage...? I dont know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected by the way the Contacts Database is organized:

1. `Contacts` - each entry represents one contact, and groups together one or more `RawContacts`
2. `RawContacts` - each entry represents data about a contact that was synced in by some `SyncAdapter` (e.g. Whatsapp, Google, Facebook, Viber), this groups multiple Data entries
3. `Data` - The actual data about a contact, emails, phones, etc. each line is a single piece of data that belongs to a single `RawContact`

You are querying phones directly from the `Data` table, as you should, so you may get the same phone number from different `RawContacts` representing the same `Contact`.

So for example, if you have Whatsapp installed on your device, and Google is syncing your contacts, the same phone number can and will be stored by 2 RawContacts per contact - one for each app.

The easy solution would be to change your Map to:

```
val contactsNumberMap = HashMap<String, Set<String>>()
```

The `Set` will enforce uniqueness over the list of phones per contact.